# Linq query diagnostics in CosmosDB SDK (.NET) for non-iterative queries

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I know that if I want to get diagnostics for a Linq query on CosmosDB, I can use ToFeedIterator and then use ReadNextAsync repeatedly and check the diagnostics on the FeedResult.  However, if the Linq query that I'm running isn't multiple results - eg. it is .Count(), .Sum() or even .Single(), I'm not sure how to go about getting that diagnostic data - I'm particularly interested in the RequestCharge.  I'm looking for a general purpose method that I can wrap up and have a layer deal with logging this for all Linq queries, not something that I need to change my whole approach every time I run a Linq query.  I've already got my own QueryProvider and Queryable to wrap these anyway, so I was thinking along the lines of intercepting QueryProvider.Execute, but not sure how to handle single results.

Answer (score 0):

I've discovered by experimentation that the CosmosDB QueryProvider will translate an expression for things like Single into an IQueryable with CreateQuery, and then the ToFeedIterator extension method can be used.  The feed iterator can then be used to retrieve the data with diagnostics, log it and return the data back from the wrapping QueryProvider's Execute method.

One thing to watch out for though is that the Enumerable QueryProvider can't handle it, so if you are abstracting from the underlying storage system like I am then you should bear that in mind in terms of how you structure your implementation